# Obtener usuario autenticado en windows en POSTGRES

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

Estoy generando los logs de las tablas que tengo en la base de datos, y en uno de los campos necesito tomar el usuario que esta autenticado en el equipo y en otro la ip que tiene,
pero cuando ejecuto el comando

```
select inet_client_addr()
```

Me devuelve la IP publica

y cuando ejecuto

```
select "current_user"()
```

me devuelve

```
|current_user |
usuariodeladb
```

ya tengo instalado el controlador de dominio, en el tengo usuarios creados, pero que otro proceso debo hacer, alguna orientación?

Comment: Por lo que tengo entendido PostgreSQL no pasa en su protocolo el usuario autenticado en el equipo

Comment: He buscado información acerca de ello, pero lo que he encontrado es muy poco quizás si exista alguna forma que tendrá que implementarse, pero gracias por leer @AnthonySotolongo